# How to make all class properties optional in Typescript

Tags: typescript

There is a way to make this:

```js
interface CreateDTO {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    price: number;
}
  
interface UpdateDTO extends Partial<CreateDTO> {}
```

But using classes, something like this:

```js
class CreateDTO {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    price: number;
}
  
class UpdateDTO extends Partial<CreateDTO> {}
```

The problem is that I have to use classes instead of interfaces because I have to add decorators for the validations.

Comment: If you make all the properties optional, are you really extending the class? Sounds like you just want to create a new class to me...

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w223xw) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: like pink said, you are just create a new class. maybe try to extract methods you want to keep to another class and `extends` that class, or define these props optional in the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's problematic to think of this as transforming one class definition (`CreateDTO`) into another class definition (`UpdateDTO`).  First, your candidate class definition

```
class CreateDTO {
    id: string; // error!
    name: string; // error!
    price: number; // error!
}
```

is failing to initialize its required properties.  If you enable [the `--strictPropertyInitialization` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictPropertyInitialization) which is included in [the `--strict` suite of compiler features](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strict) (and you should), this results in compiler errors.  Fixing those errors forces you to think about how an instance of the class should actually be constructed, say, by passing constructor arguments for the properties:

```
class CreateDTO {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    price: number;
    constructor(id: string, name: string, price: number) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

And then you can't say `class UpdateDTO extends Partial<CreateDTO>` because `Partial` acts only on *types*, and you need to extend the `CreateDTO` class constructor* value.  You *could* write a `Partial` *function* to widen class constructors of a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type `T` to that of `Partial<T>`:

```
function Partial<A extends any[], T extends object>(ctor: new (...args: A) => T) {        
    const ret: new (...args: A) => Partial<T> = ctor;
    return ret;
}
```

and apply it:

```
class UpdateDTO extends Partial(CreateDTO) { } // okay
```

But this doesn't really solve the issue, because your new class still requires those constructor arguments, since it just derives from `CreateDTO`:

```
const u = new UpdateDTO(); // error!
// -----> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Expected 3 arguments, but got 0.
```

Presumably the point of `UpdateDTO` is that it doesn't need such arguments.  You could keep pushing in this direction, but it feels like the rewards are not worth the cost.

Conceptually, the class `UpdateDTO` doesn't really *derive* from the class `CreateDTO`.  They're really more like two separate classes which somehow derive from your interface definitions `CreateDTO` and `Partial<CreateDTO>`.

---

Therefore it might be more fruitful to think of this as transforming interface definitions into class definitions.  Let's make a factory function which takes an object type definition and produces a class constructor that takes a constructor argument of that type and produces an instance of a class also of that type.  Like this:

```
function DTOClass<T extends object>() {
    return class {
        constructor(arg: any) {
            Object.assign(this, arg)
        }
    } as (new (arg: T) => T);
}
```

The implementation uses [the `Object.assign()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to spread the input argument into the instance being constructed.  Then you could make your `CreateDTO` and `UpdateDTO` classes with it:

```
interface CreateDTO {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    price: number;
}
const CreateDTO = DTOClass<CreateDTO>();

const c = new CreateDTO({ id: "abc", name: "def", price: 123 });
c.price = 456;
console.log(c); // { "id": "abc", "name": "def", "price": 456 }
```

}

```
interface UpdateDTO extends Partial<CreateDTO> { }
const UpdateDTO = DTOClass<UpdateDTO>();
const u = new UpdateDTO({});
u.name = "ghi";
console.log(u); // { "name": "ghi" }
```

Looks good.  The compiler understands that the class constructors produce instances of the relevant object types, and it works as desired at runtime.

---

The only thing I might change here is that in the case where the object type has no required properties, it would be nice not to require the class constructor to accept an argument.  If I'm going to call `new UpdateDTO({})` then `new UpdateDTO()` should also work.  So we can use a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) in `DTOClass` to make the argument optional if `{}` would be an acceptable input:

```
function DTOClass<T extends object>() {
    return class {
        constructor(arg: any) {
            Object.assign(this, arg)
        }
    } as {} extends T ? (new (arg?: T) => T) : (new (arg: T) => T);
}
```

And now you can write

```
const u = new UpdateDTO();
```

as well.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-KPRmOxoMaACi-xg6NYggAzEgye4TcwoG0sK5WQoMKyAAzTYjq9KwBDIABKEBuCFqaAAjCMyHcHu9ntE6JqoGLjabkVg0ZjfZ3DHKFRRB9OmU7ZNVW3UyVIweCGat9lxx6npmFRApgHV1vms7zBrurqMAlnaHV3VyN3SBe-VeqxMBWGhm4g9CMN6MSMjkjRmMkqppB0mRQbuxwuO4Axfo6LJAZEhoxIs-aDl8NpRNwWJ+tcZTLhQboegRWF1IQSySEgABEIBYPAjFtOkUiMfwTbsUgiFIG2ABMmYBCRIjwNMxzbAALAArAAbKqzJQBgeDTDgGAKNiN72PIf4Acgur6oRMQQICJpIuaIrfNR0S0nRlxkehxkgdsuFhF8rmmcRynka6iwvp6Jk0YQYmqq4mwdNsjEKJMjF+ZUakQBpWl1K4unqsQNZwIBjYAa2QnTt2jx9twA6efC5mIrQqKpsRi7kLOiqhFqYH7BQy5oKu9RvluO4dXE+4TswR40CeZ4Xm0ZI3oNDr3o+RAPtVlm0PCAD8RJBeuvLrVI9ILLSB1SM+Ho7Qo+0fvSqF6b+WiGRhbntYYEHNNkOScV08GjAJ-QlHeznOnZRo4eVeHA1wvmkWQKmsvAlGEhDtH0VxLFsRxsFMTxNx8QJwmieJZRSU4JxIPJSloap6madp8C6T+Bl1sFbkraO1mWvhwE+UQ82A6y3lYe5YOeQL9m+olzoBYUHqiz6hNkJFWyLLF8US8lqXaRlwRVkAA)